# Add new column in SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, northwind

I want to use the result of query to create new column in order to to find the change of freight to the revenue

The original question is **What is the impact on revenue of the additional 10% in freight**. I am currently using Northwind dataset

```
select sum(UnitPrice*Quantity*(1-Discount))  - sum(Freight*1.1) as New,  sum(UnitPrice*Quantity*(1-Discount))  - sum(Freight) as Old, New-Old
from "Order Details", Orders;
```

SQL query does not work as it does not recognize new variable "New" and "Old"

I have updated the version that suggessted but it generate error messange

```
NexusDB: Query534984250: Query execution failed: 
NexusDB: Correlation name for subquery expected:
```

```
SELECT New,Old,New-Old
FROM  (select
        sum(UnitPrice*Quantity*(1-Discount))  - sum(Freight*1.1) as New,
        sum(UnitPrice*Quantity*(1-Discount))  - sum(Freight) as Old
            FROM "Order Details"
               INNER JOIN  "Orders"  ON ("Order Details".OrderID = Orders.OrderID)
      )  ;
```

Comment: yes as when the command is run old and new are not known

Comment: do you know any way that we can store it and display it all in the query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You  can use the columns New and Old after they are run in a subquery

But your (sub)query  will not give you a correct result as

```
From `Order Details`, `Orders`
```

is a cross join between both tables and would return too many rows to give you the expected result

So you would

```
FROM `Order Details` od 
    INNER JOIN  `Orders` o ON o.id = od.order_REf_id
```

And then you still must check if the result is what you are looking for

```
SELECT New,Old, New-Old
FROM  (select 
        sum(UnitPrice*Quantity*(1-Discount))  - sum(Freight*1.1) as New,
        sum(UnitPrice*Quantity*(1-Discount))  - sum(Freight) as Old
        from `Order Details`, `Orders`
      ) t1
```

In end effect it will lokk like

```
SELECT New,Old, New-Old
FROM  (select 
        sum(UnitPrice*Quantity*(1-Discount))  - sum(Freight*1.1) as New,
        sum(UnitPrice*Quantity*(1-Discount))  - sum(Freight) as Old
            FROM `Order Details` od 
               INNER JOIN  `Orders` o ON o.id = od.order_REf_id`
      ) t1
```

Comment: which mean i have to do inner join first then write the second query as yours?

Comment: you need to replace the from Clause mentioned at the start and replace it with the second

Comment: NexusDB: Query534984250: Query execution failed: 
NexusDB: Correlation name for subquery expected:

Comment: I have update the version that I try to change based on your suggestion

Comment: yes every object needs a unique name and so it is missing a table name see edit